# Implementation of LASSO in C

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, glmnet, convex-optimization

I am trying to understand the LASSO algorithm for linear regression. I have implemented the algorithm using naive coordinate descent method for optimization. However the coefficients that I obtained from my code, wasn't matching with those obtained from the 'glmnet'package for LASSO in R. I wanted to understand how I could make the algorithm more accurate, so that the coefficients match with those obtained from R. I think they use coordinate descent as well.

Note: I have generated some toy data with 11 observations, and 6 
      features(x,x^2 ,x^3,...,x^6). The last column contains the y values 
      generated from a dummy function (e^(-x^2)). I wanted to use LASSO to 
      estimate this function. Also, I have randomly picked the initial 
      weight vector, multiple times to crosscheck my results.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int num_dim = 6;
int num_obs = 11;

/*Computes the normalization factor*/
float norm_feature(int j,double arr[][7],int n){

float sum = 0.0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    sum = sum + pow(arr[i][j],2);
}

return sum;
}


/*Computes the partial sum*/
float approx(int dim,int d_ignore,float weights[],double arr[][7],int 
i){

int flag = 1;
if(d_ignore == -1)
    flag = 0;
int j;
float sum = 0.0;
for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
    if(j != d_ignore)
        sum = sum + weights[j]*arr[i][j];
    else
        continue;
}

return sum;

}

/* Computes rho-j */
float rho_j(double arr[][7],int n,int j,float weights[7]){

 float sum = 0.0;
 int i;
 float partial_sum ;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    partial_sum = approx(num_dim,j,weights,arr,i);
    sum = sum + arr[i][j]*(arr[i][num_dim]-partial_sum);


}




return sum;
}

float intercept(float arr1[7],double arr[][7],int dim) {

int i;
float sum =0.0;
for (i = 0; i < num_obs; i++) {
    sum = sum + pow((arr[i][num_dim]) - approx(num_dim, -1, arr1, arr, 
i), 1);
}

return sum;
}


int main(){

double data[num_obs][7];
int i=0,j=0;
float a = 1.0;

float lambda = 0.1; //Setting lambda

float weights[7]; //weights[6] contains the intercept

srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));


/*Generating the data matrix */
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    data[i][0] = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    for(j=1;j<6;j++)
        data[i][j] = pow(data[i][0],j+1);
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
    data[i][6] = exp(-pow(data[i][0],2)); // the last column in the 
datamatrix contains the y values generated by the dummy function

/*Printing the data matrix */
printf("Data Matrix:\n");
for(i=0;i<11;i++){
    for(j=0;j<7;j++){
        printf("%lf ",data[i][j]);}
    printf("\n");}

printf("\n");

int seed =0;
while(seed<20) {


    //Initializing the weight vector
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        weights[i] = ((float) rand() / (float) (RAND_MAX)) * a;

    int iter = 500;
    int t = 0;
    int r, l;
    double rho[num_dim];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        rho[i] = rho_j(data, num_obs, r, weights);
    }

    // Intercept initialization
    weights[num_dim] = intercept(weights,data,num_dim);

    printf("Weights initialization: ");
    for (i = 0; i < (num_dim+1); i++)
        printf("%f ", weights[i]);

    printf("\n");

    while (t < iter) {

        for (r = 0; r < num_dim; r++) {


            rho[r] = rho_j(data, num_obs, r, weights);
            //printf("rho %d:%f ",r,rho[r]);
            if (rho[r] < -lambda / 2)
                weights[r] = (rho[r] + lambda / 2) / norm_feature(r, 
data, num_obs);
            else if (rho[r] > lambda / 2)
                weights[r] = (rho[r] - lambda / 2) / norm_feature(r, 
data, num_obs);
            else
                weights[r] = 0;

            weights[num_dim] = intercept(weights, data, num_dim);


        }


       /* printf("Iter(%d): ", t);
        for (l = 0; l < 7; l++)
            printf("%f ", weights[l]);
        printf("\n");*/

        t++;
    }

    //printf("\n");
    printf("Final Weights: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%f ", weights[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
seed++;

}

 return 0;

}
```

PseudoCode:
[image: Psedo Code]

Comment: It would be nice also to write down the pseudocode for the algorithm you're trying to implement under the hood. You don't want to mix up the details of the algorithm you're implementing, the decency of your coding, and the idiosyncrasies of a programming language...

Comment: What are the coefficients you expect versus the ones you get?

Comment: For lambda value = 0.1: Expected(from R) (Intercept)  0.88644288
V1          -0.08713527
V2          -0.23638449

Comment: I got: 0.371408 0.342732 0.378057 0.338084 0.230318 -1.458709 0.513284 (weights[6] represents the intercept)

Comment: X values used in the dataset:0.000008
0.131538
0.755605
0.458650
0.532767
0.218959
0.047045
0.678865
0.679296
0.934693
0.383502

Comment: This is what I get when I run your code on my machine: https://pastebin.com/EFyxnxkJ Does this match up with what you get on yours? (If not, there could be platform issues.)

Comment: Yes, I got the exact same results. However, they do not match with the R package: glmnet, (with lambda = 0.1) for LASSO. They implement coordinate descent as well, but the answers do not match, and their results are more accurate.

Comment: R results for the given dataset:(Intercept)  0.9039803
V2          -0.3288190 (all other coefficients have reduced to 0)